# Why don't I get a similar layout of Android Studio as displayed?

Tags: java, android

I am sorry, this is a noob question but I can't help feel isolated.

I was following an online course on Android and when they displayed the IDE for the first time it looked like this:

[Referance Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN8vK.jpg)

On the contrary, my screenshot looks like this:

[My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFqPY.png)

How do I make my Android studio display that phone and thereby preview my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the blueprint view. Click on the layout button that is located on the left of the blue button in the center and under main activity tab

Comment: Could you please a little more specific? If you are talking about these buttons: http://imgur.com/1AEnB6K, They are irresponsive

Answer (score 0):

There can be the reason that either IDE still processing the layout to display or there can be error in the XML code. If no error still you can refresh by pulling the error bar from the bottom and click refresh.

Comment: Looks like you have not installed any SDK. First open SDK manager and install SDK. Check in settings if the path to SDK is correct!

Comment: Look at your reference image. Just above Nexus device there is droid with 21, while in your screen shot it is showing null.